# Cub Cadet CCT-400 bump head component sequence on the shaft

Tags: repair, powertools

[Lookup Parts via Diagram](https://www.cubcadet.com/en_US/ari-partstream.html#/Cub_Cadet/CCT400_(41AERP3C912)_(2016)/General_Assembly/c543e2ee-9214-4b4c-95c5-5d35bdf5ff6a/dbbf2494-6bdf-45e1-89f3-3da264850cbd/y) for a Cub Cadet CCT-400 shows a high level exploded diagram.

[image: Cub Cadet CCT-400 Exploded Parts Diagram]

It is the closest I can find on how to re-install my bump head. I am not sure if I have all of the needed parts nor the sequence to put them on the shaft. Is there any standard sequence for this kind of application?

Comment: Contact the manufacturer and get a copy of the installation manual.

Comment: Did you take it apart? If you did then you should be able to put it back together.